# How to fix 'Cannot access empty property' when visiting admin/reports/databasereport?

Tags: debugging

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /home/public_html/sites/all/modules/dba/database/mysql.report.inc on
>   line 44

I get the above fatal error on a WSD when clicking on */admin/reports/databasereport*  (using Drupal version 7.22).

Any idea what it means and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the [Database Administration module](https://drupal.org/project/dba) before but when i looked on the line 44 of that module and I found that:

```
$value = new stdClass();
$query = db_query('SHOW GLOBAL STATUS');
foreach ($query as $row) {
  $column = $row->variable_name;
  $value->$column = $row->value;
}
return $value;
```

It means you can't fetch the data from 'SHOW GLOBAL STATUS' SQL statement. So i think maybe your current MYSQL account didn't have right to do that.

Comment: This is supposed to be a module bug. i.e the above piece of code should check the results of the query before processing it.

Comment: That's right. They should check the result of db_query before using foreach.

Comment: Is it a complicated fix?  Sorry, I am really a neophyte with php. :)

Comment: Can you go to phpmyadmin and login by username/password MYSQL and after that run the script ''SHOW GLOBAL STATUS' from here. If you can't please go to cpanel and change the permissions for that user. From my view i just have thought like that.